# include all the script tags from a file

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using html and angularjs .I have index.html where i am using many (may b 13) scripts and link tags.I want to make the code clean .So i want to import all the scripts and link tags from a file.So basically what i want to do is

```html
<head>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>                  
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mainpage.css">
</head>
```

Should become as

```html
<head>
    //add all the tags from the file include.html or include.txt something
</head>
```

I searched a lot and didn't get any working solution.Please help.Thank you

Comment: Yea, you found no solution because its not possible in the way you want it - by only using HTML/JavaScript. You could load your JavaScript ressources async by using http://requirejs.org/. If you are using a backend based language like PHP, Python, Java or JavaScript (Node.JS) you could create a header template and render it before responsing your View to the client.

Comment: okay ! what would be the ideal solution for making the code clean other than using requirejs.org ?

Comment: Your code is fine, most complex webpages have many more scripts included in the head tag than you have. If you aren't using any other languages other than html & js just leave it as it is

Comment: IMO its clean. What is wrong by adding the ressources in the header part as it is expected in HTML? Outsourcing / refactoring makes sense if you have dozens of ressources to load. You could also take a look at "uglify" & "minifiy" JavaScript / CSS ressources.

Comment: also bear in mind that `<script src="javascripts/jquery2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` is already shorthand and minified, it's not like you have the whole jquery script in your header, justa link to it

Answer (score 0):

Store your links in JSON format file 
,Read your JSON file , run a for loop and call the following lines

```
var importedScript = document.createElement('script');
 importedScript .src = '/path/to/imported/script';
  document.head.appendChild(imported);
```